# Basic Python String Concatenation + Math Issue, Code Included

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
age = 11
days = age*52*7    
decades = age/10    
estimate = round(decades)    
summary = "I am " + {} + " days old! Thats about " {} " decades!".format(str(estimate), str(decades))
```

Where is the syntax error?

Comment: When you run it, where does it say your error is?

Comment: I am following the TeamTreeHouse track to learn python, so it is within their "workspace." The error they give is : SyntaxError: summary = "I am " + {} + " days old! Thats about " {} " decades!".format(str(estimate), str(decades))

Comment: What are those `{}` doing there?

Comment: Direct answer:  Your error is on line 5... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the format syntax incorrectly. The curly brackets go inside your string, so:

```
summary = "I am {} days old! Thats about {} decades!".format(str(estimate), str(decades))
```

Comment: Thank you, that will fix my problem!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could do that (not specifying values between the curly braces.)

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Yep, you can. It probably better practice to specify the value, but for a short string like this, it doesnt really matter :).

Answer (score 2):

Your [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) line is incorrect.

```
summary = "I am  {} days old! Thats about  {}  decades!".format(estimate, decades)
```

Unlike other answers, notice that I also removed the `str` from your `format` tuple. It is not needed.

---

You may wish to look at output message as well. It currently outputs `I am  1.0 days old! Thats about  1  decades!`. At last check, a decade is more than 1 day.

This error is occurring because of this line:

```
estimate = round(decades)
```

Your `estimate` uses the `decades` variable, instead of your `days` variable

Comment: What would cause this to happen? I have reformatted my script as the following... age = 17
days = age*52*7
decades = age/10
estimate = round(decades)
summary = "I am {} days old! Thats about {} decades!".format(estimate, decades)

Comment: thanks for your effort. I believe there is a problem with TeamTreeHouse's backend then, as they will not let me proceed without first diving my age/10 and attaching that to the variable decades.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `format` incorrectly. It should be like this:

```
summary = "I am {0} days old! Thats about {1} decades!".format(str(estimate), str(decades))
```